# how to combine two variables into one foreach?

Tags: php, mysql

How would you combine two variables into one foreach?

```
$variableOne
$variableTwo

foreach($? as $data)
{
    print data here from both variables
}
```

Comment: Googling `php merge arrays` will get you the answer :)

Comment: Are they arrays? Are they values? Are they objects?

Answer (score 2):

Very simple buddy:

```
$new_array = array_merge($variableOne, $variableTwo);
foreach($new_array as $data)
{
    print data here from both variables
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Last question, how would I print the data inside the foreach, do I use $data or would I use the variables name? Obrigado!

Comment: `$data['some_value'];` To see the content inside $data, try `print_r($data)`

Comment: Ta bom, vlw! (Thanks report back soon)!

Answer (score 0):

If those variable aren't arrays, you may try

```
foreach(array($variableOne, $variableTwo) as $data){
  echo $data
}
```

Comment: How would I print the data from each variable though?

Comment: I meant, the data that is returned from both the variables. If I 
$test = array($latestArticles, $articleTags); print_r($test); I get arrays returned, how do I print those arrays? Would I just do the following as an example? $first = $data['array1']; and so on? Or would I need to use the variables name?